Jenkins pipeline failed for run ant unit test case
I am running below Jenkins pipeline to run unit test case with Jacoco and ant but it showing me stylesheet error, but when I run same ant command from server its working fine. I have attached Jenkins Pipeline code for reference.
pipeline {
    agent any

    tools {
      jdk 'java17'
    }
    

    stages {
        stage('Run Ant Commands') {
            steps {
                script {                    
                     sh '''
                        cd ${hybris_platform_dir}
                        ant unittests -Dtestclasses.extensions=girlscoutsfacades -Dtestclasses.reportdir=/tmp/unittests -Dstandalone.javaoptions="-Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT,CLDR -javaagent:/home/ec2-user/jacoco/lib/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=/tmp/unittests/jacocounittests_all.exec"
    
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

This is the error which Jenkins shows: Errors while applying transformations: stylesheet null doesn't exist.
I have mentioned few lines where I'm getting errors from Jenkins
[yunitrep] Processing /tmp/unittests/TESTS-TestSuites.xml to /tmp/null837604609
[yunitrep] Loading stylesheet jar:file:<path>/lib/ant-junit.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit/xsl/junit-frames.xsl

I have tried running the same ant command from server and its working file.
